# How to console.log in Watir?

Tags: ruby, testing, watir

How can I log to console in `watir`? Or break in the code. Like Javascripts `console.log` or `debugger` statements.

`puts` doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get full debugging info output to console by setting `$DEBUG = true`

`puts` should still work, though, so I'm not sure what is going on in your system.

Comment: Puts works fine for me. Maybe the OP is waiting for an output in the browser window, which is not going to happen. Puts outut will be mixed with the server output at console.